# How recursion works in this code snippet?

Tags: python, recursion

```
def tri_recursion(k):
    if(k>0):
        result = k+tri_recursion(k-1)
        print(result)
    else:
        result = 0
    return result


tri_recursion(8)
```

## output of the function with argument 8

```
1
3
6
10
15
21
28
36
```

Answer (score 2):

In the beginning of the code, we have a function. It is `def` or otherwise known as define. It has the variable of k. If you think about it, its like algebra. f(x). the f in the example or the `tri_recursion` is the name of the function and the x in the example or the k in `tri_recursion(k)`. Now that we know this, lets go down to the rest of the code. The next part has an `if` or `else` statement. This interprets that if k is greater than 0 then it will have another variable called `result` that is `equal` to `k` plus `tri_recursion` minus one. It will then print the result. If the requirements are not met in the if statement, it will move down to the `else statement`. It says that result is equal to 0. Then at the end, it will `return` the value of result. `Return` is only used in functions.

> This is how it increments by

```
1
3 Increase by 2
6 Increase by 3
10 Increase by 4
15 Increase by 5
21 Increase by 6
28 Increase by 7
36 Increase by 8
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

It's a bottom-up recursion.
It will first go aaaaall the way down to `tri_recursion(0)` and then it will start building bigger answers until it gets to 8. So

tri_recursion(0) = 0

This one is not printed. From here on, all gets printed, resulting in that list.

tri_recursion(1) = 1 + tri_recursion(0) = 1

tri_recursion(2) = 2 + tri_recursion(1) = 3

tri_recursion(3) = 3 + tri_recursion(2) = 6

tri_recursion(4) = 4 + tri_recursion(3) = 10

tri_recursion(5) = 5 + tri_recursion(4) = 15

tri_recursion(6) = 6 + tri_recursion(5) = 21

tri_recursion(7) = 7 + tri_recursion(6) = 28

tri_recursion(8) = 8 + tri_recursion(7) = 36

Hope this is useful to you!